# Is there a text editor in Windows that will render color coded python structlog output (or a way to do this in Notepad++)

Tags: python, notepad++, structlog

I have output from a python program that is being logged for the most part by structlog.  When viewed in the console it is color coded but Notepad++ doesn't seem to recognize the characters that are being used to do the color coding.

Is there a text editor that will render this text as color coded?

Is there a way to do this in Notepad++

This is what the output looks like in a console window:
[image]

This is what the output looks like in Notepad++
[image]

Comment: In general, text editors wouldn't respect custom formatting. You could try loading the log into something like VS Code, though, which might be able to do syntax highlighting, just by looking at the log structure.

Comment: There was an [issue](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/8078) for this on notepad++ and the discussion had [this python script](https://github.com/Ekopalypse/NppPythonScripts/blob/master/npp/error_list_lexer_support.py). It seems you can load the script using a plugin (info is in the repo README)